# Using conditionals inside {{each}} loop

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I have this helper

```
Template.clientesPromo.helpers({
  'mostrarPromosCliente' : function(){
     return Promociones.find({'metadata.modalCliente' : Session.get("val") });
  }
})
```

And using it like this

```
<template name="clientesPromo">
{{#each mostrarPromosCliente}}
<p style="color:#666; display: inline-block;">{{metadata.diaOferta}}</p>
{{/each}}
</template>
```

And that works it Return for example Monday, Thuesday etc, but i want to do the next

if diaOferta its equal to Monday,thuesday, etc (the 7 days of the week) the helper return "all days of the weeks" instead of monday,thuesday etc,

**note** The data on mongo with the name of metadata.diaOferta its an array of days

its there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<template name="clientesPromo">
{{#each mostrarPromosCliente}}
<p style="color:#666; display: inline-block;">{{getValue}}</p>
{{/each}}
</template>
```

Create another helper

```
Template.clientesPromo.helpers({
  'mostrarPromosCliente' : function(){
     return Promociones.find({'metadata.modalCliente' : Session.get("val") });
  },
  'getValue':function(){
       //here you can access metadata.modalCliente using **this.metadata.modalCliente**
       var days=this.metadata.modalCliente;

       //logic to checkj whether all days exists or not
       if(allDays){
         return "all days of the week"
       }
       else{
         return this.metadata.modalCliente;
      }

  }
})
```